# Integrate Sass in Angular2 - webpack

Tags: angular, sass, gulp, webpack, angular-cli

I created a new angular2 project using the [angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)(@1.0-webpack.2).

I would like to integrate [Sass](http://sass-lang.com) with my project.

I know that:

- I can use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for this
- it's possible to [include SCSS in ng2 components](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components)

What I'd preffer is to have a specific directory for `.scss` files which should be 'watched' and compiled once they change, like `.ts` files after `ng serve`(terminal).

Thank you

[image: Angular 2 project(CLI) tree view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment (Aug 25th) this is not possible, but it will be possible with the next release of the angular-cli.

In the angular-cli.json file there will be a property names `styles` which will be an array of paths to style files which when referenced will be included in your application.

You can see me demo this feature in this [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obbdFFbjLIU)  (starting around the 12 minute mark)

Comment: Since the new "@angular/cli" has been released, is there a official tutorial?

Comment: Probably like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular2-angular-cli-sass-options/41541042#answer-39816365

Answer (score 0):

You should move `index.html` to `dist`. If you want to incorporate the scss build into your webpack build, add the following to your webpack config:

```
{
    output: {
        filename: './dist/[name].js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: './app',
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['exports-loader?module.exports.toString()', 'css', 'sass']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./styles.css')
    ]
};
```

You can then include `scss` files in ng2 components with `styles: [require('path-to-scss')]`