# Angular-cli from css to scss

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular6, angular-cli

I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), which says that if I want to use `scss` I have to run the following command:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

But when I do that and make that file, I still receive this error in my console:

> ```
> styles.bundle.js:33Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT:
> no such file or directory, open
> '/Users/Egen/Code/angular/src/styles.css'(…)
> ```

Comment: That will only work for files you generate from that point, I don't think it will fix the ones you already have. If you `git diff` you will see what it's changed.

Comment: But I've no files yet. Just want to switch.

Comment: how do you have no files yet? If you're creating a new project, why are you configuring it that way?

Comment: Just starting with angular2. I'm trying to figure it all out.

Comment: If you're creating a new project, do `ng new whatever --style=scss` **as shown in the docs**. Don't follow the instructions for configuring an existing project if that isn't what you're doing!

Comment: get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.

Comment: even for an existing project I'd probably just create a new one with the desired settings, overwrite my current project's config files with the newly generated ones and check the diffs for changes I want to keep

Answer (score 369, accepted):

**For Angular 6** check the [Official documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors)

*Note:* For `@angular/cli` versions older than `6.0.0-beta.6` use `ng set` in place of `ng config`.

### For existing projects

In an existing angular-cli project that was set up with the default `css` styles you will need to do a few things:

1. Change the default style extension to `scss`

> Manually change in `.angular-cli.json` (Angular 5.x and older) or `angular.json` (Angular 6+) or run:
>
> ```
> ng config defaults.styleExt=scss
> ```

if you get an error: `Value cannot be found.` use the command:

> `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`

(*source: [Angular CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options))

2. Rename your existing `.css` files to `.scss` (i.e. styles.css and app/app.component.css)
3. Point the CLI to find styles.scss

> Manually change the file extensions in `apps[0].styles` in `angular.json`

4. Point the components to find your new style files

> Change the `styleUrls` in your components to match your new file names

### For future projects

As @Serginho mentioned you can set the style extension when running the `ng new` command

```
ng new your-project-name --style=scss
```

If you want to set the default for all projects you create in the future run the following command:

```
ng config --global defaults.styleExt=scss
```

Comment: EDIT: I just needed to refresh the real-time builder. It works correctly

Comment: Just a helper note use url for importing remote styles in scss version : like this : @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons");

Comment: @angular/cli 1.7.3: changing defaults.styleExt from `css` to `scss` in `.angular-cli.json` will automatically create scss files for every new component generated in the future.

Comment: ng set defaults.styleExt scss for existing projects

Comment: I'm using the new Angular 5 template with .NET core 2.1 preview. When I did these steps, I get the following results in my browser:

"Cannot GET /"

I don't seem to get any console errors, nor any compile errors.

Comment: Angular6: you'll find "angular.json" instead of ".angular-cli.json" - the steps defined above are the same

Comment: for angular 6 follow this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors

Comment: `$ ./node_modules/.bin/ng config defaults.styleExt=scss`
Value cannot be found.

Comment: @chovy for latest angular cli version, in my case(6.0.7) use this command for existing projects: `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`  as told by @hamilton.lima

Comment: For renaming existing css files, 1. Install renamer `npm i -g renamer` 2. Change directory to src and run command `renamer --path-element ext --find css --replace scss "**"`

Comment: I can confirm this still works with angular `11.2.3` migration from css to scss using material.

Comment: With Angular 12 you'll get `Data path "/schematics/@schematics~1angular:component" must NOT have additional properties(styleext)` - Use `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.style scss` instead

Answer (score 75):

As of ng6 this can be accomplished with the following code added to `angular.json` at the root level:

Manually change in `.angular.json`:

```js
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "styleext": "scss"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have `schematics` not at the root level but nested inside my project in `angular.json`. Should I ignore that and add this at the root level instead?

Comment: @mcheah, yes that is how mine is setup as well, and it is working.

Comment: I left mine nested inside the project and it looks like that's working fine too, just as an FYI for anyone who has the same question.

Comment: After updating to ng6 latest versions my `schematics` is now nested as well.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything for me. Still not processing scss rules in .css files.

Comment: it's working. By default project creation time it will be "schematics": {}. we ahve to add  like below post

Comment: How do you then deal with the `"styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],` part? Do you manually change it to `src/styles.scss` and then also rename the file itself?

Comment: Note - `styleext` was renamed to `style`.

Answer (score 53):

Open **angular.json** file

1.change from

`"schematics": {}`

to

```
"schematics": {
           "@schematics/angular:component": {
                   "styleext": "scss"       
             }  
  }
```

2. change from (at two places)

`"src/styles.css"`

to

`"src/styles.scss"`

then check and rename all `.css` files and update component.ts files styleUrls from `.css to .scss`

Comment: Step 1 can be done from CLI: `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
` as specified in official docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors

Comment: If you're on Angular v9 or greater, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782667/2506393

Answer (score 41):

In latest version of Angular (v9), below code needs to add in `angular.json`

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  }
```

Could be added using the following command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.style scss
```

Comment: is not working for me and i'm trying to do it over 10

Comment: Angular 10 here, works. Notice the difference of `"styleext"` and `"style"` in this answer

Comment: This still works for Angular 14, took me quite a while to find it since most answers use `styleext` as @Pierre pointed out

Comment: Most accurate answer now. This one worked with angular 14. 
`ng set` seems deprecated. 
`ng config defaults.styleExt=scss` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 17):

First install in your project:

`npm i --save-dev schematics-scss-migrate`

In your Angular CLI project:

run below command:

`ng g schematics-scss-migrate:scss-migrate`

Above command will do the following in the consuming project:

1. Rename all the stylesheets in the **src** folder recursively.
2. Alter the **styleUrls** in respective component classes to point to the new file names for stylesheets.
3. Updates the component styles schematics value in the **angular.json** file or creates one if the schematic does not exist, and
4. Renames all **styles.css** references to **styles.scss** in the **angular.json** file.

I have tried this on my angular 9 project and it worked...no need for extra efforts for renaming files... just enter the command and BOOM!!! now your project is migrated to scss project.

refer:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/schematics-scss-migrate

Comment: how is your answer different from the ones already given? I'd recommend you improve an existing one by editing it (if you have the edit right).

Comment: I am on Angular 12, and this answer is the best for me, just two commands and boom, everything is done!. 
@jasie his answer is different in the sense that if you have hundreds of components and stylesheets you don't have to do so manually as that would be a huge pain, you simply run two commands from the terminal and all changes are made instantly.

Comment: I am using angular 9, this is working fine for me, btw I had to downgrade `node-sass` package btw to 4.0.0.

Answer (score 16):

**For existing projects**:

*In `angular.json` file*

1. In `build` part and in `test` part, replace:

   `"styles": ["src/styles.css"],` by `"styles": ["src/styles.scss"],`
2. Replace:

   `"schematics": {},` by `"schematics": { "@schematics/angular:component": { "style": "scss" } },`

> Using `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext
>   scss` command works but it does not place the configuration in the
>   same place.

*In your project* rename your `.css` files to `.scss`

**For a new project**, this command do all the work:

```
ng n project-name --style=scss
```

**For global configuration**

New versions seems to not have a global command

Answer (score 14):

For Angular 6,

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

note: @schematics/angular is the default schematic for the Angular CLI

Answer (score 12):

**CSS Preprocessor integration for Angular CLI: 6.0.3**

When generating a new project you can also define which extension you want for style files:

```
ng new sassy-project --style=sass
```

Or set the default style on an existing project:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

[Angular CLI Documentation for all major CSS preprocessors](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors)

Comment: `Invalid JSON character: "s" at 0:0.`

Comment: As of Angular CLI 6.0.8  `ng config` (as above) is the best method BUT you still need to rename `*.css` files to `*.scss` AND replace references in `angular.json` to `style.css` with `style.scss` AND update all component file references in `styleUrls` property to the new names. ... then it works great!

Answer (score 7):

A quick and easy way to perform the migration is to use the schematic NPM package `schematics-scss-migrate`.
this package renames all css files to scss files :

```
ng add schematics-scss-migrate
```

https://github.com/Teebo/scss-migrate#readme

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to choose the `from` and `to` style format that's it! I didn't rename it manually.

Answer (score 6):

Use command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

Answer (score 6):

manually change the below code in "angular.json" which will be at the end of the file.

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  }
```

Kindly rename the files from .css to .scss and change all the references to the same

Comment: Looks same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/67903727/4826457 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69110323/4826457

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, I looks similar and even the answers which you have mentioned is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782667/11983640.

Answer (score 5):

There's obviously more than one ways to do this, but with the recent versions of angular I got another schematics value which I wanted to preserve. Because of this other value the command `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss` failed for me, so I took the new value and entered it myself in `angular.json`. This is the new value you have to enter:

```
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
```

And `angular.json` looks like this at the end:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  ...
  "projects": {
    "yourapp": {
      ...
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
...
```

Then you'll have to

- rename all the `css` files to `scss` and
- change all the references in your files to those.

You should be done with those steps.

Answer (score 4):

**A brute force change can be applied.**
This will work to change, but it's a longer process.

Go to the app folder **src/app**

1. Open this file: **app.component.ts**
2. Change this code `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']` to `styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']`
3. Save and close.

In the same folder **src/app**

1. Rename the extension for the app.component.css file to **(app.component.scss)**
2. Follow this change for all the other components. (ex. home, about, contact, etc...)

The **angular.json** configuration file is next. It's located at the project root.

1. Search and Replace the css change it to **(scss)**.
2. Save and close.

Lastly, Restart your `ng serve -o`.

If the compiler complains at you, go over the steps again.

Make sure to follow the steps in **app/src** closely.

Answer (score 3):

In ng6 you need to use this command, according to a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425616/no-config-found-or-get-set-have-been-deprecated-in-angular-6):

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component '{ styleext: "scss"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

For users of the [Nrwl extensions](https://nrwl.io/nx) who come across this thread: all commands are intercepted by Nx (e.g., `ng generate component myCompent`) and then passed down to the AngularCLI.

The command to get SCSS working in an Nx workspace:

`ng config schematics.@nrwl/schematics:component.styleext scss`

Comment: Brilliant, was looking for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 11+

Manually change in `angular.json.`

Replace the `"schematics": {},`

with

```
  "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
```

Answer (score -1):

for angular version 12
Just rename styles.css file to styles.scss and update angular.json src/styles.css to src/styles.scss