# Unable to get .scss instead of .css while generating new angular components

Tags: angular, sass, angular6

I want .scss files to get generated when i create new components through angular cli, but i am get .css files. 
Tried adding defaults

```
"defaults": {   
     "styleExt": "scss", 
}
```

in angular.json but it did not work. 
I am working on latest version i.e Angular 6.
Anyone knows how to get this ?

Comment: you need to add that in .angular-cli.json (root folder of your angular project) and not in angular.json.

Comment: I am on angular 6. it doesn't have angular-cli.json, i can see only angular.json for configurations.

Comment: which version of angular-cli are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular-cli from css to scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss)

Comment: try a new project with angular-cli and see how it works...

Comment: also they changed the name (in v5.0 i think) to `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: I am using 6.0.0 version of angular-cli

Comment: Also tried  ->  ng config defaults.styleExt=scss and ng set defaults.styleExt=scss  ---------  which is giving error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not like previous versions,

```
"defaults": {   
     "styleExt": "scss", 
}
```

You need to replace the above lines with below code.

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  }
```

You can easily set the style while creating the project with below code.

```
ng new project_name --style=scss
```