# Switching Angular 5 PrimeNG project to scss from css throws "module build failed: undefined"

Tags: css, angular, sass, primeng

Currently I want to change my default Style from css to scss because I want to be able to use variables in my style files to be able to set properties based on certain theme properties.

I followed the instructions from [Angular-cli from css to scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss), but all I get is an "undefined variable "$font-family" in the "_theme.scss" file from PrimeNG.

I am using Angular 5.2.5 with PrimeNG 5.2.6.

I have no idea how to fix this, please help me.

[image]

Comment: please share ng config command which you are using to debug easily