# Where to put GULP and SASS in Angular 5 project

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, gulp

I am working on angular 5, I want to automate javascript using gulp.js and CSS by using SASS, But I am confused where to put gulp and Sass files in my project folder and how to link them with my app component.

Comment: are you using angular CLI?

Comment: Yes, I am using angular CLI!

Comment: Just [convert to scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss) as your style ext and the CLI will take care of what you want for you with ng serve / build. :)

Comment: and what about gulp files? can i reference them as it is in my app component?

Comment: Absolutely, you'll include all that into your angular.json, just give a quick google on Angular CLI scss + gulp and you can set it up for whatever but in reality you'll probably end up just phasing out external gulp stuff all together and let the CLI handle whatever tasks you're using them for.

Comment: okay thank you for your time

Comment: No worries, if you run into specific issues come back and we'll get you sorted. Welcome to SO :)