# Angular 6 mixes styles in project

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, gulp

I'm new in Angular 6, so the problem is that I've got main.min.css file, and don't know where to put it. Styles.sass, app-component.sass, or directly into component folder. Please explain me what's the difference between them, and where I should put this file.

main.min.css file was created by gulp, I'm using webpack, maybe that's a problem?

Comment: while generating the angular cli project which did you choose css or sass ?

Comment: I chose sass while generating. I notced that it works perfect with css, but structure was <body><body><body>some code</body></body></body>

Comment: is the stylesheet  common for all component then  you can add it in root component  / app component, else in the specific component you want

Comment: also be specific what you are trying to achieve ? are you trying to use this css file along your Style.sass file ?

Comment: Yeah, I changed stylesUrl to this main.min.css, instead of styles.scss. This css file have global styles for all project.

Comment: so you will have to change it manually in angular .json also , also  if you are going to use css instead will have to rename every .sass files generated with each component  to .css  . check this article will help you  (this one's to convert css to sass): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss

Comment: I'll read, thx a lot. I figured this problem out at the beggining of developement, so maybe it will be easier to rebuild angular cli, and restart dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild project with css, instead of sass