# Angular 6 project with Sass

Tags: css, angular, sass

So, I've made a migration of a Angular 5 project to Angular 6 (well, more like I did a mix with a regular migration and a new project re-using the files because of a bunch of problems). The project compiles and works nicely as it should.

Bu the Angular 5 version used `sass` instead of the regular `css`. That shouldn't be a problem: I did the following updates to allow Angular 6 to work with the `scss` files.

- `schematics` in `angular.json` is set with `"@schematics/angular:component": { "styleext": "scss" }`
- `style`in `angular.json`is set with `"styles": [ "src/styles.scss" ]`
- All the `css` files have a `scss` extension.
- All the component have a `scss` declared instead of the `css`.

Well... That didn't work. My pages are rendered without style whereas the files seem to be correctly loaded. Did I miss something?

(Angular version is 6.1.10, CLI is 6.0.8)

## Update 2

- The console does not write anything related to a missing file or else.
- The styled elements don't have their style.
- In the DevTools the styles are not the sources tab, but they also aren't in it in the Angular 5 version (though they are in the Style Editor tab in Firefox).

Comment: check the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss/45255290

Comment: Already did all that.

Comment: Looks like you did everything OK. Did you change the styleUrls in your components? e.g. `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']` to `styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']`

Comment: Yeah, the url have been updated too.

Comment: We need more details to help you. Did the console wrote something? If you inspect the styled elements, do you see your styles? In chrome DevTools, source tab, do you see your styles?

Comment: Consider creating a new project using `ng new my-project`, and importing your files to it. Looks like your problem can't reproduced.

Comment: Weeeell, I did that too... And guess I'm out of luck: not working again. The thing is, if I put a simple `body { background-color : red }`, the scss work. So I don't really know why the style isn't fully working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: there were missing dependencies in `style` and `scripts` in `angular.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to compile the `scss` files.

- do `npm install -g sass`
- then run `sass styles.scss`

which will turn/compile `scss` files to `css` one.

You cannot link a direct `scss` files to render styles, it must be compiled first to `css`.

Comment: I don't think that's it. If I begin a new project using directly sass, it seems to work.

Comment: He is using the Angular CLI and does **not** need to add scss manually or transpile it manually!

Comment: might be a file path error? or you have `styles.sass` but you've written `styles.scss`. **probably**

Comment: The extension is `scss`.