# Failed to find 'functions scss error in angular application

Tags: angular, sass

I have created a brand new angular 7 application and installed it with scss. After building the application I am getting the following error

My **style.scss** class has the following import

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

I can also see a functions files under bootstrap folder of `node_modules`

> ERROR in ./src/styles.css
>   (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   Error: Failed to find 'functions' in
>   [C:\Development\360-manager\src\WebUI2_0\manager-ui\node_modules\bootstrap\scss]
>   at resolveModule.catch.catch
>   (C:\Development\360-manager\src\WebUI2_0\manager-ui\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)

Comment: @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; try something like this

Comment: i tried that and still get error ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'
  in [
    C:\Development\360-manager\src\WebUI2_0\manager-ui\src
  ]
    at resolveModule.catch.catch (C:\Development\360-manager\src\WebUI2_0\manager-ui\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now and I'm trying to solve it. BTW .. try with something like @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"

Comment: try  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"`.
See: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader

Control `@import URL` resolves the given URL in the runtime.
To import styles from a *node_modules* path prefix it with a `~`.
So  `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` imports everything from the folder:
*node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap*

Comment: Still gives me an error Failed to find 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap' in my Angular 7.2 project. Bootstrap version is 4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when my project was configured to use css. Consider changing it to scss first. How to can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45255290/234110)