# Errors within Angular project relating to scss and css mix up and style preprocessor options

Tags: css, angular, sass, preprocessor

In the project linked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2eovfno2pwfbru/Wholesale-cli.zip?dl=0), I'm creating a website that will show some property listing That I will have under contract. I'm having some mix ups between using the scss and css file. The tutorial I watched, the person used scss files. After discussing with a friend, I decided to used css instead. Now I'm having trouble in terms of trying to write code in css with out the style preprocessor options. Since i'm on visual code I usually use the problems tab in order to help me debug. But the errors are only in the terminal.

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B1Tt.png)

Also, with the latest version of angular 6, does anyone know how to implement the style preprocessor options?

---

After doing what was suggested:

i changed the stylesURL and wanted to test with ng serve -o

[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvU5c.png)

I then used the command `ng config defaults.styleExt=css`:
[Shown Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jO7J.png)

Comment: when you go to your header.component.ts file. What does your @Component selector has when its referencing 'styleUrls', what is the extension on your file?

Comment: ```import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: "ws-header",
        templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
        styleUrls: ["./header.component.scss"]
    })

    export class HeaderComponent {

    }```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In the future: best practice is to include the text of the error messages, rather than as images.

Answer (score 0):

in your `header.component.ts` file change this `styleUrls: ["./header.component.scss"]` to this `styleUrls: ["./header.component.css"]`

And try running this command `ng config defaults.styleExt=css` and try following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss#answer-45255290) answer

That should fix your error.

Comment: It didnt work :(, hold on a sec, I'll edit the question and show what im talking about

Comment: I was able to build your project without issues. I first commented everything out in the styles.css file. Mainly because you have both css and scss in that file which is causing issues. Delete any .scss references. Delete the src/styles/_.scss file. and delete the .scss file from the header folder. Also change the header.component.ts file to reference styles .css as in my answer above. This should build your project just fine