# Install Hamburger CSS on Angular

Tags: css, angular, hamburger-menu

My intention is to install the [Hamburger CSS from Jonathan Suh](https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/) on my Angular Project.

I used `npm i --s hamburgers` which successfully added the package. I also added its CSS file to my angular.json file.

When I try to add a hamburger using the code below, the hamburger is being displayed, but it's not clickable. Why is that?

```
<button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
    </span>
  </button>
```

Comment: doc:https://www.npmjs.com/package/hamburgers

Comment: @לבנימלכה As far as I'm concerned I did everything that's mentioned, except of SASS.

Comment: I think you must use sass of this

Comment: @לבנימלכה I‘m using Angular with CSS - can I just use a SASS file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss

Comment: @לבנימלכה But I still want my default Stylesheet to be CSS, that’s not possible?

Comment: from doc `.scss source files are available if you use Sass as your CSS precompiler. It’s customizable and modular.`

Comment: you can do this aniamtion alone with css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps to follow,

1. install hamburger package. `npm install hamburgers --save`
2. import in styles.scss `@import '~hamburgers/_sass/hamburgers/hamburgers.scss';`
3. use hamburger divs in html and toggle the class. `(click)="active=!active" [ngClass]="active ? 'is-active' : ''"`

Answer (score 2):

As you comment that you use **CSS** and in doc write:

> .scss source files are available if you use **Sass** as your CSS
>   precompiler. It’s customizable and modular

[Here is alternative with angular and css](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-ldqpsa?file=src/app/app.component.css)

**Html**

```
<div class="collapse" (click)="ifShow=!ifShow" [ngClass]="{'hide':!ifShow}">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.collapse{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse span{
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: black;
}

.collapse span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px;
}
.collapse span:nth-child(3){
    top: -10px;
}

.hide span:nth-child(2) {
   transform:rotate(45deg);
   top:0;
}

.hide span:nth-child(3){
   transform:rotate(-45deg);
   top: 0;
}

.hide span:nth-child(1){
  animation:hideMain 1.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.hide span:nth-child(2),.hide span:nth-child(3) {
  animation:hide 1.5s;
}

@keyframes hide{
  0%{
    transform:rotate(0);
  }
  50%{
    top:0;
    transform:rotate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes hideMain{
  49%{
   opacity: 1;
  }
  50%{
  opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

**TS:**

```
 ifShow : boolean = true;
```