# Why is my Angular CLI Creating CSS instead of SCSS Files?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9

Prior to updating to [Angular 9](https://angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-9), my project was configured to use SCSS when the `ng generate` command was run, and indeed it did.

Much to my dismay, after running my first `ng g c` on Angular 9, it added a `css` file rather than a `scss` file.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss) to this does not appear to work any longer.  My `angular.json` includes the following (as it has for the past two years):

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
```

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: `styleext` is now deprecated, you should use `style` instead.

Answer (score 13):

Please try like this.

In angular.json, set "schematics" as below to default scss when generate new component

```
"schematics": { "@schematics/angular:component": { "style": "scss" } }
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently upgraded my Angular CLI to v12 and generated a new project. I opted to generate scss files for new components. After creating a component, I saw that css files were being generated, not scss files. I ran the below command and now when I generate a new component, the scss file is created and not css.

`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.style scss`