# Use assets from the Angular library in the application

Tags: angular, angular-library

I'm using **Angular 8** and I have a separate application with its own CSS styles and assets. I want to embed the library component inside the main application like

```
<lib-landing-page-preview></landing-page-preview>
```

The directory structure is

[image]

The library assets are inside the `/projects/landing-page-preview/src/assets` where the `style.scss` is the main CSS file inside the `scss` directory.

The root `angular.json` file has been updated

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    ... // main application project
    "landing-page-preview": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/landing-page-preview",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/landing-page-preview/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/landing-page-preview/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/landing-page-preview/ng-package.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "*/*",
                "input": "projects/landing-page-preview/src/assets",
                "output": "src/assets"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/landing-page-preview/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/landing-page-preview/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/landing-page-preview/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/landing-page-preview/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/landing-page-preview/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "qcg-frontend"
}
```

While development, I'm the library is build using following command

```
ng build landing-page-preview --watch
```

and running the main application using

```
ng serve
```

**But the assets files in the library directory does not seem to be working.**

The `ng build landing-page-preview --watch` command gives

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(assets).
```

Comment: what do you mean does not seem to be working? Are they not being displayed, is that what you meant?

Comment: The CSS styles are not being applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of bits about your `angular.json` that seem amiss.

I had a similar problem when I created a project that wasn't `SCSS`. I then needed to convert it. I can't see any reference to SCSS in your angular.json. The fix for that was to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss). You could add `schematics` information in your `angular.json` if scss isn't parsing at all (see example below).

The next thing is that if you are adding extra styles, you need to add their location in the `angular.json`.

Below is an example where I have added additional styles to a project and got the SCSS to compile. See comments for where to look (I have added something that would hopefully be right for that extra lib folder).

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myprojectname": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {   /* SCHEMATICS INFO - REMOVE THIS COMMENT */
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/lib" /* ADD EXTRA ASSETS LIKE THIS HERE AND REMOVE THIS COMMENT */
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss" /*<- ADD EXTRA STYLESHEETS HERE AND REMOVE THIS COMMENT */
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "...": "..."
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "...": "..."
        },
        "test": {
          "...": "..."
        },
        "lint": {
          "...": "..."
        },
        "e2e": {
          "...": "..."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "myprojectname",
  "schematics": { /* SCHEMATICS INFO - REMOVE THIS COMMENT */
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```