# How to apply angular-material built in theme variables in component style?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to create a dynamic `background-color` for my `.active` class of my `mat-list-item`

HTML:

```
<mat-list-item
      *ngFor="let page of pages"
      matRipple
      routerLinkActive="active"
    >
      <a [routerLink]="page.path" (click)="drawer.close()"
        ><mat-icon class="mat-18">{{ page.iconName }}</mat-icon
        >{{ page.name }}</a
      >
</mat-list-item>
```

So now basically assigning `.active {background: red}` works as expected. What I wanted to do is apply the built in `theme` `$primary` color value. I'm using Angular Material `indigo-pink` theme so I've tried doing the following

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

.active {
  background-color: $primary;
}
```

This throws error

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
   │   background-color: $primary;
   │                     ^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

Anything that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color variables are declared in `scss` files, while you are importing `css`. I.e. you cannot get sass variables via importing compiles css files.

If you want doing it properly you need to follow https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components guidelines.

E.g. getting material colors:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent,
  )
));

$color: mat-get-color-config($theme);

$primary: map-get($color, primary); 

.candy-carousel {
    // Use mat-color to extract individual colors from a palette.
    background-color: mat-color($config); // color will be there
    border-color: mat-color($config, A400); // a bit different hue
}
```

Comment: Throws `$map: null is not a map`

Comment: What version of angular material do you use? My example is for v10, other versions have a bit different syntax.

Comment: Mine is also `v10`. I'm so confused right now while using `hues`. What if I want to use a different palette color? Like for example I want it to use `lighter` value of the primary color. How should I do that?

Comment: If you want a bit different color you need to specify second argument for `mat-color` mixin. I updated the example. `mat-color` also supports opacity.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working a while to get this working as expected. This is a compilation of what I have done to make this work more or less smoothly with few lines of codes (using `angular 11)`:

1. I changed all my files from css to scss following the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss)
2. I created a style to contain this primary variables:
   2.1. At the same level of `app` I created a folder `styles` with the name `styles` and inside a file `_variables.scss` with this content:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Theme configuration
$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
```

2.2. I add the file to my styles inside `angular.json`:

```json
...
            "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/_variables.scss"
            ],
            "scripts"
...
```

3. From my component `my-component.scss`)I was now able to access the file and variables like this:

```css
@import "~/src/styles/_variables.scss";

.primary {
  color: mat-color($primary) !important;
}
```