# Is it possible to convert the global styles.css file to styles.scss?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have an application that was build using the Angular CLI, Angular version 11. I have some directives in my application that require specific css classes. Rather than have separate scss files for each directive I would like to add the scss classes to the styles.css contained in the application root. However I can't do this as the styles.css file is css and not scss. Is there a way I can convert this file to scss?

Comment: You can simply change the file extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726081/angular-cli-from-css-to-scss

Answer (score 0):

I just manually changed the file extension and changed the reference in the angular.json file in the `{ "architect": { "build : { "styles": } } }`property - so far I have experienced no unexpected behavior or errors