# Styles in the root are not getting applied in angular-cli project

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-cli

I am working on an angular-cli project. I am using SCSS and they're getting compiled and I can observe the changes of them.
styles.css and app.component.scss in the root path are neither getting compiled nor can observe the changes.

[image]

Here it's the root folder structure. style.css is compiled to the root structure (This is done in angular-cli.json)

```
"styles": [
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "../node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
      "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css",
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
      "../node_modules/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css",
      "styles.css"
    ]
```

You cannot see the style.css because, it's hidden using vscode settings.
What is wrong here and how can i get the changes applied here?

Comment: the styles-array in angular-cli.json does not compile anything to styles.css,
it tells the cli that styles.css should be part of the bundled styles in dist.

Comment: the app.componenent.scss is injected in the component and does not get a unique css-file, it should "just work"

Comment: it should "just work". Exactly @JohanBlomgren . The issue is it's not getting compiled even that's in the root directory. And there's a app.component.css , but new changes are not getting compiled there.

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI ?

Comment: what made the app.component.css? if you use angular-cli's scss support you don't get css-version of every scss-file

Comment: @JohanBlomgren I used angular-cli to make the app component. FYI - Each time I create a component, a SCSS file is added in the component. It's configured in the angular-cli.json

Comment: @Ploppy yeah. I am using angular-cli

Comment: And if you change something in the component.scss -file like a color or font-size does the actual result show in your app when you do "ng serve " or "ng build " ?

Comment: For app.component.scss 's changes are not shown in the app. but, browser refreshes.
 In the created components it shows up the changes. @JohanBlomgren

Comment: so the changes to app.component.scss are shown in your browser when you browse to that component?

Comment: Nope. That's the issue. Changes are not shown for app. component.scss. But, the other  components I made in the root directory detect the Scss changes.

Comment: I would copy the code to a temp-file and re-create the component

Comment: I found 'ng g c <component-name>' handy. :) , By the way, thanks for the consideration to help. @JohanBlomgren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this.
The problem I encountered was because of initially when my project was created the default extension for styles was CSS and it has been changed by the time since styling with SCSS is much prettier.

So, the issue was the previous configuration in angular-cli.json. when the compilation happens, it doesn't detect the change in the SCSS file, but its search for a CSS
This was the answer helped me to understand the mistake - [Angular2 - Angular-CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular2-angular-cli-sass-options)

PS - It's where I went on the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What version of angular cli are you using?

I was using 1.0.0-beta.22-1 and styles.css was not properly being bundled in the prod build.  Downgraded to 1.0.0-beta.19-3 and it works again.  Seems to be a bug in the later cli project.

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.18 is the version um using