# Install bootstrap-material-design in angular 2 app using Angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, bootstrap-material-design

I want to use [bootstrap-material-design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) in my **Angular 2** application that uses **angular-cli**.

bootstrap-material-design (V4) uses SASS. And in order to make it work in Angular 2, I need to use [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader). But I didn't find any solution to make **Angular-cli** uses sass-loader since webpack configuration cannot be overrided (In my knowledge).

Is there any solution to use `bootstrap-material-design` in a **Angular 2** application that uses **angular-cli** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular-cli with sass without and loader. You can just set your prefix to sass or scss as you wish.

Check this out

[Angular2 - Angular-CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular2-angular-cli-sass-options/39816365#39816365)

Comment: Unfortunately, telling angular-cli to use sass rather than css does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID , did you find any solution for using bootstrap material in angular2 cli project ?

Comment: I use now [angular2-materialize](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize) which is based on [materializecss](http://materializecss.com).