# Architecture for using SCSS with Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, architecture, sass

I am trying to setup an architecture for using `SCSS` with my **angular 4** project rather than plain `CSS`. Uptil now i have followed the [Angular Style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) to arrange CSS simply adjacent to components `ts` files with each component having a separate directory, as in following the feature first approach.

Since now i am moving to using `SCSS`, i simple replaced my `CSS` files with `SCSS` files. But i am not able to understand, where exactly should i put my `_variables.scss`, `_mixins.scss`, and common `styles.scss` files, such that variables are always the first to load, so that variables dependencies can be resolved in the `SCSS` files.

I am using webpack to compile my `SCSS` files.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
        },
        {
           test: /\.scss$/,
           use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: "sass-loader" }
            ]
        }
    ]}
```

Since i am not very good at designing and architecturing an app, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have several options there. we used bootstrap and sass. you need to include sass bootstrap package into your project. ref: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-3-and-Sass-and-ngx-bootstrap

Comment: Do you know any way of doing it without including bootstrap or some other styling library? My project requires me to build my own CSS framework for an angular widget library with as less space as possible.

Comment: you can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433995/using-sass-in-angular-2

Comment: FYI: `ts` and `scss` loaders are already built in Webpack 2.x

Comment: @deezg I do not just want to use local component variables but rather global variables to be used around the whole web app. For ex- `$colorPrimary`, `$colorAccent`, the post you mentioned only shows how to use local variables.

Comment: @Nikolai Did you use a global `_variable.scss` file as well ? If yes, then how exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone developed a **seed** angular application with considering `SASS` and perfect architecture and everything else one might need.

Have fun exploring it. This Worked wonders for me.

[Angular Library Seed](https://github.com/trekhleb/angular-library-seed)

Answer (score 2):

If you want some common style code, and you're already using Webpack,
then you can simply import the common styles into your main module.
For example:

Directory Structure

```
/src
  /app
    app.component.html
    app.component.ts
    app.component.scss
  /styles
    _mixins.scss
    _variables.scss
    common.scss
  app.module.ts
  main.ts
```

In your app.module.ts file you can `import './styles/common.scss'`,
which will basically have all of your mixins and such imported into
it. Your app.component.scss file will likely want to import "../styles/variables"
and perhaps some mixins too.

The other option to having common stylesheets is to simply import the
parts whenever you need them into component *.scss files rather than
bringing them all in at once. This could prevent you from importing
parts that you don't really need.

Comment: I did as you asked. I have imported my `variables.scss` inside `app.component.scss` and my `app.component.scss` file inside the `AppComponent` using `styleUrls: []`. But still inside other components `SCSS`, variables are not getting resolved.