# Angular CLI: Loading SCSS as separate files in browser

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am including `scss` file as given below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ....,
    styleUrls: ['../../scss/dashboard_admin.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardAdminComponent implements OnInit {
.....
```

It is compiling the `SCSS` to `CSS` very well, but loading the styles in `<styles>` tag, I would like to include them as separate `CSS` file.

Here is the SCSS related config from `.angular-cli.json`

```
"defaults": {
     "styleExt": "scss",
     "component": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if your project isn't configured to use preprocessors, you need to include compiled `CSS` files in `styleUrls`, like this:

```
styleUrls: ['path/to/compiled/css/dashboard_admin.css']
```

Browsers can't read SCSS, SASS, LESS (and so on), just give compiled valid `CSS` file to them.

But if you want to use SASS for example, you need to configure Angular CLI when generating new project or you can do it for existing project.

Here is the good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541042/6053654

Comment: Thanks, I will check on this. How can I compile `CSS` to a folder? I am using Angular CLI. What config changes I have to make?

Comment: @Vikram, it seems like you need to configure angular CLI when you generating new project. But if your project is already exists, you can do the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541042/6053654

Comment: @Vikram, and please, upvote if my answer is useful for your case

Comment: I have already done those changes in cli config file. Like set `styleExt` to `scss`> I guess, I have to make changes in webpack config.

Comment: @Vikramm I don't have any experience with webpack, but can assume that you have to do it. May be this link will help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1647

Comment: Just added .angular-cli.json info for scss in question.