# Angular CLI add SASS after the project has been created

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 project created using the Angular CLI.

I know that when you are using the Angular CLI you can create a project that uses SASS like this:

```
ng new ProjectName --style=sass
```

**My question is:** "Can I use the Angular CLI to install SASS after a project has been already created without it?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to style with `ng set` after installing `node-sass`

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev 

ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

Taken from here: [Angular CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options)

Comment: there is no reason to run `npm install node-sass --save-dev` as `node-sass` just gets installed by default and not listed in `package.json` file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), install it by running the following command:

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

Then, if you want to use SASS syntax, run:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt sass
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular CLI - just do

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

All new components will use SCSS not CSS. Though if you just want to start using SCSS - changing existing .css files to .scss files will work. The relevant compiler is already present *batteries included*

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it manually you can also do that by changing the angular cli configuration file

in your .angular-cli.json change style css to scss

```
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss"
  }
```

And then install `node-scss` to compile your scss files

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```