# Write CSS in Sass files throwing error in Angular 7

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am trying to write a simple css syntax within component's sass files in angular 7, but i am facing a compilation error as shown below.

[image]

sass file only contain simple css as shown

```
.full-width {
   width: 100%;
}
```

In earlier angular versions, I didn't have such issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the file extension of your SCSS file, you're actually using SASS, an older version of SCSS. As indicated in the docs for the [Sass syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax), the SASS language uses indented syntax.

From the [section on SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#the-indented-syntax):

> *The indented syntax supports all the same features as SCSS, but it uses indentation instead of curly braces and semicolons to describe the format of the document.*

What you should do would be to either change the file extension of that SCSS file to `.scss`, or convert the SCSS syntax to SASS.

Comment: Hi, thanks. It worked. Can you please tell me the project configuration that I need to change so scss format works all over the project and by default .scss files should be created rather than .sass?

Comment: @UmairJameel See this other question on StackOverflow for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619327/using-scss-sass-as-default-style-sheet-in-angular-6-styleext (TL;DR - run `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss` in your terminal to set the configuration property)

Answer (score 2):

Is this **SASS** or **SCSS** ?

if this is SASS, then the brackets **are** invalid. just remove them for valid SASS.

```
.full-width 
   width: 100%;
```

if you want to keep the brackets, then you want to use the SCSS language instead.

Check the guide here to see the differences between the two: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: Hi, thanks. It worked. Can you please tell me the project configuration that I need to change so scss format works all over the project and by default .scss files should be created rather than .sass?

Comment: that should have been an option when you created a new angular app, but if you look inside the `angular.json` file it should list which language is being used for styles.  Check this article out for instructions on how to change the language via a CLI command: https://medium.com/@manivel45/configuring-angular-7-project-with-sass-bootstrap-and-angular-material-design-69b0f033dc04