# New angular app ignoring the default scss style extension in .angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular5, angular-cli

I want to set the default style extension on my Angular project to scss and whenever new component is created - .scss files to be generated by default. I am using these versions of Angular CLI:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.7".
```

I've manually set a default styleExt - scss in my .angular-cli.json:

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {},
    "schematics": {
      "collection": "@nrwl/schematics"
    }
  }
```

However, when I try to create a new app using the:

```
ng g app admin
```

or

```
ng g app admin --style=scss
```

I still get .css files. 
I've also tried to set the default styleExt to scss by running

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

but that doesn't change anything. It always generates .css files. It seems like the default value is ignored. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your existing Project css to scss

change your angular-cli.json defaults object like this

```
"defaults": {
    "schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
```

More Info:[Angular CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nrwl, you can set the default stylesheet extension by running the following command:

`ng config schematics.@nrwl/angular:component.styleext scss`

The main reason why you need to do this is, because they moved all the functionality to `@nrwl/angular` (it was in `@nrwl/schematics`).

More info about this in the [nrwl nx repo](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1488)