# How to Remove Sass Dependencies from Existing Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, sass, npm-install

Have inherited an Angular 7 app set up to use Sass.  We actually don't use sass so, long story cut short, I want to simplify the build pipeline and remove need to install Python and Windows Dev Tools.

I've followed the instructions as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options)

to configure the application to use css over sass but it doesn't change the actual dependencies.  When I do npm install, it still tries to install sass-loader etc and run python.  None of these sass dependencies even seem to appear in package.json so I can't even get rid of them manually.

Angular seems to have gone very black box...  Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Pretty sure all you need to do is change the config on `angular.json` where `"@schematics/angular:component"` is located to use `scss` so the value would be `"styleext": "scss"`. Then rename all your `sass`extension to `scss`

Comment: That's what I thought but npm install is still doing all the sass, gyp stuff etc and running python. I just want rid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that dependency comes from the angular devkit as an optional dependency. github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/… . Installing with --no-optional should skip it.

As for the other parts of the build, someone else will need to recommend something, but it might not be worth the time investment since it's a framework (strictly opinion).

<strike>You'll likely have to do a mass file rename. You could do a script to check every app file and change from sass to scss. At the same time, you'll have to look for every reference inside of a file and make the same change.</strike>

As far as "css" stuff SCSS *is* SASS (two different syntaxes), just the new version (Sassy CSS).

As far as package dependencies, the same "SASS" dependencies are still used.

Comment: There is no sass in the project at all just css. I can't work out how or why there are these sass dependencies because I didn't create the app.  I don't want the added overhead of Wndows Build Tools in my CI environment so I need to remove the sass dependencies from the project.  There appears to be no apparent way of Doing this in Angular 7 - I can't even see entries for these packages in package.json.

Comment: Oh, I misread css as scss.. My bad!
Anyways, I believe that dependency comes from the angular devkit as an optional dependency. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/package.json . Installing with --no-optional should skip it.

Comment: Yes - uninstalling angular devkit and then reinstalling with npm install --no-optional @angular-devkit/build-angular seemd to do the trick.  Thanks for your help.