# Angular 7: generating @angular/material component give sass file with css syntax

Tags: angular, sass, angular-schematics

after generating a new project with Angular CLI and choosing SASS:

```
Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SASS   [ http://sass-lang.com   ]
```

adding material with ng:

```
 ng add @angular/material
```

and finally generating  the nav-bar component of material with:

```
ng generate @angular/material:materialNav --name=main-nav
```

Gives us a main-nav.component.sass with a css syntax:

```
.sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 200px;
}

.sidenav .mat-toolbar {
  background: inherit;
}

.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Anyone knows if it's possible to generate from @angular/material with sass syntax?

Thank you

Comment: There is a github issue [Material schematics don't support legacy "Sass" format](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/15153). Where @jelbourn says ``We currently only support the more recent `.scss` format (or anything that's a superset of css)``. Their plan is ``If the user's project is configured to use `.sass` (not `.scss`) or Stylus, we should emit plain CSS files``, see: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/15164

Comment: ok, so that's the reason why, thank you fridoo

Answer (score 0):

suffix with --style switch with the required style sheet

```
ng generate @angular/material:materialNav --name=main-nav --style=sass
```

You can refer this SO link 
[Angular CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options) for more options and understanding

Comment: thank you for the answer but i already tried and it still gives mea SASS file with css syntax. Just tried again, and yes, i confirm, the syntax is css, not sass

Comment: I think you need to set it globally in your angular CLI.