# I'm trying to generate new component but getting the response Option "styleExt" is not defined

Tags: angular

I have already checked [Angular CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options/39816365) link,but it didn't work for me and getting the same error `Option "styleExt" is not defined` while generating the new component.

I also tried with `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` command but it gives the response like  `get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.`

so i am unable to genereate new component in my project.

Here is my angular.json file.

**angular.json** file

```
   {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "AngularDemo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
         "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/AngularDemo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularDemo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AngularDemo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularDemo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "AngularDemo-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "AngularDemo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "AngularDemo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "AngularDemo",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816365/1331040 `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`

Comment: I have already refer it but i did't work for me.

Comment: @SandySanap what's the command you're running exactly ?

Comment: i tried with ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a mistake in your `schematics` configuration file. 
Just change `"styleext": "scss"` by `"styleExt":"scss"`.

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleExt":"scss"
    }
 }
```

Its work fine.

Comment: I am glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `angular.json`

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleExt":"scss"
    }
}
```

Delete **node_module** folder and run **npm i**.