# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js)

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular-material

I'm trying to run my angular 14 app but getting the following error while trying to serve it locally. Have a look at the error below:

```
Build at: 2022-06-28T06:24:59.368Z - Hash: 217d45d22093a51f - Time: 5857ms
 ./src/app/app.component.sass?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Expected newline.
  ╷
1 │ .example-icon {
  │               ^
  ╵
  src/app/app.component.sass 1:15  root stylesheet


** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✖ Failed to compile.
```

Here is my *package.json* dependecies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.8.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^12.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  },
```

*app.component.html*

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>

  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Second Line</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <mat-icon
      class="example-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="Example user verified icon"
    >
      verified_user
    </mat-icon>
  </mat-toolbar-row>

  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Third Line</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <mat-icon
      class="example-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="Example heart icon"
    >
      favorite
    </mat-icon>
    <mat-icon
      class="example-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="Example delete icon"
    >
      delete
    </mat-icon>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

*app.component.sass*

```
.example-icon {
  padding: 0 14px;
}

.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

My environment:

Angular CLI: 14.0.0
Node: 14.18.0

I am not being able to build the angular project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason for the error is that you're using a SASS file instead of SCSS. ([What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass)) According to your syntax you want to use SCSS. So you should rename you style file to `app.component.scss` and change the Angular CLI to use the SCSS syntax with this command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

You can also take a look at this post here to change the Angular CLI options to your preferred syntax:

[Angular CLI SASS options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options)

If you want to write the styling in SASS, you've to write it like this:

```
.example-icon 
    padding: 0 14px 
.example-spacer 
    flex: 1 1 auto
```